# cant hide the inflated layout - android

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I am trying to make an accordion in android myself,
so I want when someone clicks on the `LinearLayout` that the Layout which contains the `listview` appears and after the second click it must disappear
so I created this code, but I don't know why it does not disappear and put another layout.

```
        LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
    int state = 0;

    Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.book_activity);


        mLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.intro);

    }

    public void Get_List(View view)
    {
        View inflated = LayoutInflater.from(BookActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.chapter_activity,null,false);
        mLinearLayout.addView(inflated);


        if (state == 0)
        {
            inflated.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            state = 1;
        }else if (state == 1)
        {
            inflated.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            state = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the XML of the Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:textDirection="rtl"
    android:background="#75cdc0"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="nashat.com.trftqbook.BookActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:scrollY="35dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cover" />


        <ScrollView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:fillViewport="true">



            <LinearLayout
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">



                <LinearLayout
                android:background="@drawable/listbutton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/intro"
                android:onClick="Get_List"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="المقدمة"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />
                 <Button
                     android:visibility="gone"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     android:text="asdasd"
                     android:id="@+id/inflated_button"/>
            </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:background="@drawable/listbutton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/chapter_one"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="الباب الأول"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textColor="#FFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:background="@drawable/listbutton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/chapter_two"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="الباب الثاني"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textColor="#FFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:background="@drawable/listbutton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/chapter_three"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="الباب الثالث"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textColor="#FFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:background="@drawable/listbutton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/chapter_four"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="الباب الرابع"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textColor="#FFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:background="@drawable/listbutton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/chapter_five"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="الباب الخامس"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textColor="#FFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:background="@drawable/listbutton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/chapter_six"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="الباب السادس"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textColor="#FFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:background="@drawable/listbutton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/chapter_seven"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="الباب السابع"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textColor="#FFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:background="@drawable/listbutton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/chapter_eight"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="الباب الثامن"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textColor="#FFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:background="@drawable/listbutton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/chapter_nine"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="الباب التاسع"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textColor="#FFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>



        </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

thanks

Comment: I suggest that you look at DrawerLayout. It does all of this for you.

Comment: post your main_activity layout xml

Comment: @SantanuSur i put it

Comment: @Code-Apprentice sorry but i didnt understand

Comment: DrawerLayout is a class provided by the Android API which does what you are trying to do. I encourage you to google it and see if it fits your needs.

Comment: thanks but i want to know why it doesnt disappear when the result equals 1